# How to request a certificate from a CA on a remote machine using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to invoke a PowerShell command on a remote computer. I'd like to request a certificate from an in-house CA.  If I run the following command directly on the remote PC the operation is successful:

```
Get-Certificate -Template 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9612972.3074733.7357589.1249582.14248002.117.5480590.5436517 -Credential $cred -Url ldap: -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

When I run the following command from a remote computer on the same domain I get the WIN32: 87 error shown below.  I have googled the error extensively and cannot figure out the issue (fyi.. I have mitigated the double hop issue earlier in my script by using Enable-WSManCredSSP).

```
 $user = 'ABCCOmpany\<password>' #We are using the local machine's Administrator account
 $password = ConvertTo-SecureString '<password>' -asplaintext -force
 $credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $password
 $RequestAndReceiveCertificateSuccessful = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock{param($cred) Get-Certificate -Template 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.9612972.3074733.7357589.1249582.14248002.117.5480590.5436517 -Credential $cred -Url ldap: -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My} -ArgumentList $credential
```

Error:

```
The parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Certificate], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.GetCertificateCommand
+ PSComputerName        : Agent3
```

Comment: Does the local account have rights to request that certificate from the CA? Instead of passing the creds as a parameter, try using `$using:credential` within your `Invoke-Command` scriptblock. I don't know if the creds are getting serialized when being passed that way.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I tried using your method and I get the same error: WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.